# Include 2 entities in 1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable

I have an entity Auto (car)

```
public class Auto : BaseDbEntity
{
    public string Kleur { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatumGekocht { get; set; }
    public string Nummerplaat { get; set; }
    //relations
    public Eigenaar HuidigeEigenaar { get; set; }
    public AutoType HuidigeAutoType { get; set; }
}
```

And 2 entities linked to this one, Eigenaar (owner) and AutoType

```
public class Eigenaar : BaseDbEntity
{
    public string Voornaam { get; set; }
    public string Achternaam { get; set; }
    public string Naam => $"{Voornaam} {Achternaam}";
}

public class AutoType : BaseDbEntity
{
    public string Merk { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

In my AutoDataService I have the following:

```
public List<Auto> GetAllAutosSortedByName(AutoCriteria criteria)
{
    return GetFullyGraphedAutos()
        .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.Name))
        .OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
}

private IIncludableQueryable<Auto, AutoType> GetFullyGraphedAutos()
{
    return _entityContext.Autos.Include(x => x.HuidigeAutoType);
}
```

This way I have the AutoType entity linked to the main Auto entity. But I can't figure out how to also link the 3rd entity "Eigenaar" since IIncludableQueryable only allows for 2 parameters.

I would assume it needs to look something like this

```
private IIncludableQueryable<Auto, AutoType, Eigenaar> GetFullyGraphedAutos()
{
    return _entityContext.Autos.Include(x => x.HuidigeAutoType).thenInclude(x => x.HuidigeEigenaar);
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, is there another function I should use to accomplish this?

Comment: Can't you simply do `.Include(...).Include(...)`? It's been a while since I've done EF without lazy loading.

Comment: No because IIncludableQueryable<> only allows 2 parameters.

Comment: Any reason you want to use that specific interface though?

Comment: I can't find an alternative. I'm not very familiar with interfaces. So I'm basically asking if someone knows a fitting alternative. Or just any other way to solve this.

Comment: `IQueryable<Auto>` probably works. (No editor at hand, so can't try it out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not depend explicitly on `IIncludableQueryable`, just continue to return `IQueryable` to follow the conventions of LinQ:

```
private IQueryable<Auto> GetFullyGraphedAutos()
{
    return _entityContext.Autos
        .Include(x => x.HuidigeAutoType)
        .Include(x => x.HuidigeEigenaar);
}
```

I will also suggest you to use the asynchronous version of the I/O bound methods of `DbContext` (the ones that actually execute the query, like `ToList`, `First`, etc), specially given that you are working on a web application:

```
public async Task<List<Auto>> GetAllAutosSortedByNameAsync(AutoCriteria criteria)
{
    return await GetFullyGraphedAutos()
        .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.Name))
        .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```